# SpeechSynthesizer - How do I play/save the wav file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, speech-recognition

I have the following code snippet in an ASP.NET app (non Silverlight)

```
 string sText = "Test text";
 SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 ss.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);
 ss.Speak(sText);
 //Need to send the ms Memory stream to the user for listening/downloadin
```

How do I:

1. Play this file on the browser
2. Prompt for the user to download a wav file?

Can anyone help with completing the code?

**EDIT: Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the main bit to an IHttpHandler that does what you want. Plug the handler URL into a bgsound tag or pipe it to whatever to play in-browser, and add a querystring check for a "downloadFile" var or something to conditionally add a Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=whatever.wav header if you want to download. No intermediate file is necessary (though there is weirdness with the SetOutputToWaveStream thing failing if it's not run on another thread).

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    { 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/wav";

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                ss.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);
                ss.Speak("hi mom");
            });
        t.Start();

        t.Join();
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: For 1) I tried 
        ms.WriteTo(Context.Response.OutputStream);
        ms.Close();
with no luck. Am I missing something.
2) The code does not produce a wav file as far as I can tell. How do I let the user download a wav/mp3 file without having to save it in a temp location on the server?

Comment: That process works for me- generates a wav stream of the spoken text. I don't know the context of the browser stuff you're doing- you can't render HTML in the same response or anything. You'd need to use an embed tag and pass parameters to a handler to generate the wav output or something...

Comment: What I am trying to do is synthesize text to speech and give the user an ability to either (1) listen to it on the browser or (2) download the file. For (1), I understand I need the embed tag, but do I need to save a temp wav file that the embed tag points to? For (2), I set the contenttype, but it doesn't seem to be working. Could you please post a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: When I add your code to a WebMethod, I get the "Timeout not supported" exception. Any clue?

Comment: The actual exception is System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
  at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()

Please help. I am stuck!

Comment: Hmph- nice bug on their part (it should ignore a failure on ReadTimeout). Just write a wrapper class that responds to ReadTimeout (just return whatever). Just make a class that extends Stream and delegates to another stream for everything but ReadTimeout.