# Cannot hear audio from ASP.NET "Text to Speech" Application

Tags: asp.net

in my asp.net project, I code below for a text to speech function.
in my page's c# file.

```
 byte[] SpeakText(string text) 
        { 
            using (SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer()) 
            { 
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
                { 
                    s.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms); 
                    s.Speak(text); 
                    return ms.GetBuffer(); 
                } 
            } 
        }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (TextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Response.Write(SpeakText(TextBox1.Text));

            }

        }
```

but not hear the audio while run it.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: What happens while running the debugger? Have you set any breakpoints in the `SpeakText()` method?

Comment: In your code you are just returning the Converted Wave format of the text given, but where you are playing the text??

Comment: You're doing Response.Write(SpeakText(TextBox1.Text)); - so your wave output goes to (HTTP) client. How is this data processed on client side?

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the response content type:

```
Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
```

Also don't use `Response.Write` as it expects encoded characters. You need to write binary to avoid getting corrupt data:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
Response.BinaryWrite(SpeakText(TextBox1.Text));
Response.End();
```

Comment: And add a `Response.End()` to skip adding html to that sound.

Comment: I have try but could hear the sound at the page.
now my code is below:
    ' byte[] SpeakText(string text) 
        { 
            using (SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer()) 
            { 
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
                { 
                    s.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms); 
                    s.Speak(text); 
                    return ms.GetBuffer(); 
                } 
            } 
        }'

Answer (score 0):

your code is executing on the server, not on the client machine.

Once you have generated the Speech output you should stream it down to the client (as a wav file for example), check this answer for a full example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1719867/559144

Comment: I have view the http://stackoverflow.com/a/1719867/559144
how to call ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
how to set value for context at asp.net button click function.