# SpeechSynthesis fails to SelectVoice under ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Speech Synthesis fails to SetVoice(). All are listed as enabled, until it's tried, then fails with the non-default two listed as 'disabled'.

NOTE: This works on a WPF or Console app, but fails as an ASP.NET app.
ALSO: Speech is created on an alternate thread (Task.Run(()=>StartSpeech()) since it permanently locks the main thread for ASP.NET applications (see [No response to a HTTP Get request in WebAPI in .NET 4.5 while using SpeechSynthesis for converting text to speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036942/no-response-to-a-http-get-request-in-webapi-in-net-4-5-while-using-speechsynthe) for details). However, the SelectVoice() fails on both the alternate thread as well as the main.

Ideas?

```
        private SpeechSynthesizer speech; //System.Speech.Synthesis
        var voices = speech.GetInstalledVoices();
        //[0]: "Microsoft David Desktop" ["Enabled"]
        //[1]: "IVONA 2 Emma" ["Enabled"]
        //[2]: "Microsoft Zira Desktop" ["Enabled"]

        try
        {
            speech.SelectVoice( "Microsoft Zira Desktop" );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var p = e; //fails (System.ArgumentException: Cannot set voice. No matching voice is installed or the voice was disabled)
        }

        voices = speech.GetInstalledVoices();
        //[0]: "Microsoft David Desktop" ["Disabled"]
        //[1]: "IVONA 2 Emma" ["Enabled"]
        //[2]: "Microsoft Zira Desktop" ["Disabled"]

        speech.SpeakAsync( text );
```

Comment: Hi Jim, is it failing on your local machine or in production ?

Comment: local machine where wpf/console apps work fine.

Comment: Thomas - you got me thinking about rights/processes... new info: it fails under IIS ONLY. Running locally (VS-f5-iis-express) - it works. odd.

Comment: Ok I am going to try now

Comment: looks like LocalSystem (Identity) works through IIS, but ApplicationPoolIdentity does not. Apparently the SelectVoice() is a rights-enabled call where simply speaking isn't.

Comment: Ok good to know it ^^

Comment: thanks for the back and forth - certainly helped!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this even worked under Visual Studio IIS Express, but failed under IIS. Switching from ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem made it work. Seems like SelectVoice() is a rights-enabled call where simply speaking isn't.

Answer: Change Application Pool's Identity (in IIS) to LocalSystem.